# Read file from src/main/scala using sbt

Tags: sbt

`src/main/scala/my/pkg/Main.scala` reads `src/main/scala/my/pkg/file.txt` successfully when running from IntelliJ. When I run it, in `target/scala-2.11/classes/my/pkg` there are class files for Main as well as the `file.txt`

When I run it from sbt, it fails reading `file.txt`, it's not there in `target/scala-2.11/classes/my/pkg`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

build.sbt:

```
Compile / unmanagedResources += baseDirectory.value / "src/main/scala/my/pkg/file.txt"
```

and `scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(getClass.getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(file)).getLines()`
did the work